# Proving $\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{k}=\Theta(n\sqrt{n}).$

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

How can I prove this complexity?

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{k}=\Theta(n\sqrt{n})$$

The theta notation means [a quantity bounded in the limit both above and below by constant multiples of the given expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations).

Comment: @DavidMitra Surely the $\sqrt n$ is intended to be a $\sqrt i$.

Comment: For $\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt k$: Do you know [Euler-Maclaurin formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler–Maclaurin_formula)? Or [Stolz-Cesàro theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz_theorem)?

Comment: With this new edit it looks even more hilarious :)

Comment: sorry again !that is first Question !

Comment: Does anyone here but the OP know what that $\;\theta\;$ there means?!

Comment: The big theta notation is a mistery to me: according to Wolfram, it means "that is not much worse but also not much better" than $\;f\;$..." This sounds like a Broadway musical's criticism, not mathematics!

Comment: @DonAntonio: Per the Wikipedia page linked in my edit, $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$ means there exist positive constants $k_1,k_2$ s.t. $k_1 g(n) \le f(n) \le k_2 g(n)$ for all sufficiently large $n$.  If you write a lyric, I will set it to music and post it on YouTube.

Comment: Great @hardmath ! I bet critics will shred us to pieces...

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{i} \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{n}=n \sqrt{n}$$
and 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{i}  \geq \sum_{i=\lfloor \frac{n+1}{2} \rfloor}^n \sqrt{i} \geq \sum_{i=\lfloor \frac{n+1}{2} \rfloor}^n \sqrt{\frac{n}{2}} \geq \frac{n-1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}= \frac{n\sqrt{n}}{2 \sqrt{2}}-\sqrt{\frac{n}{8}}$$